# align elements in 2 columns and make it center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi i am trying to achieve this [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxDqJ.jpg . but i am unable to center it and make it responsive that means it should changed to small on small device.

```css
.content-wrapper {
  min-height: 926px;
  background-color: #d9dde2;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #f89b0f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: #f89b0f;
}

a {
  color: #f39c12;
}

.content-header>.breadcrumb {
  background: #f89b0f;
  right: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 1200;
}

.solid-header-default {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.solid-header-success {
  background: #00a65a;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.gcircle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #938005;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle-block {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

.circle.circle-navy {
  background: #938005 !important;
}

.circle.circle-blue {
  background: #01205F !important;
}

.circle.circle-red {
  background: #C00000 !important;
}

.circle.circle-pink {
  background: #7030A1 !important;
}

.circle.circle-green {
  background: #44AA20 !important;
}

.circle.circle-yellow {
  background: #FFC100 !important;
}

.circle.circle-light-blue {
  background: #0F70D7 !important;
}

.circle.circle-black {
  background: #151515 !important;
}

.circle span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.cchart {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
}

.brandlogo-image {
  float: left;
  line-height: .8;
  margin-left: .8rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  margin-top: -6px;
  max-height: 34px;
  width: auto;
}

.circle-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center-me {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background: #fff;min-height:926px">
    <div>



      <ul class="center-me">

        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>











    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background: #F99B10;height:926px">

  </div>
</div>
```

i have achieved this so far [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmbgZ.jpg  . i just want to be same all screen type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using grid to align your elements center horizontally and vertically. Please see class `.center-me` CSS for details. I have commented out one of the div on the first column so that the height of `.center-me` div will follow parent container.

```
    .center-me {
      /* text-align: center; */
      display: grid;
      height: 100%;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      align-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
  min-height: 926px;
  background-color: #d9dde2;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #f89b0f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: #f89b0f;
}

a {
  color: #f39c12;
}

.content-header>.breadcrumb {
  background: #f89b0f;
  right: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 1200;
}

.solid-header-default {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.solid-header-success {
  background: #00a65a;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.gcircle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #938005;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle-block {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

.circle.circle-navy {
  background: #938005 !important;
}

.circle.circle-blue {
  background: #01205F !important;
}

.circle.circle-red {
  background: #C00000 !important;
}

.circle.circle-pink {
  background: #7030A1 !important;
}

.circle.circle-green {
  background: #44AA20 !important;
}

.circle.circle-yellow {
  background: #FFC100 !important;
}

.circle.circle-light-blue {
  background: #0F70D7 !important;
}

.circle.circle-black {
  background: #151515 !important;
}

.circle span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.cchart {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
}

.brandlogo-image {
  float: left;
  line-height: .8;
  margin-left: .8rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  margin-top: -6px;
  max-height: 34px;
  width: auto;
}

.circle-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center-me {
  /* text-align: center; */
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background: #fff;min-height:926px">
    <!--<div>-->



      <ul class="center-me">

        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-navy"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="circle-li">
          <span class="circle circle-blue"><span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></span></span>
          <div class="cchart">
            <b>WEBCAMS</b>
            <div>Hold Visual Meetings</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>











    <!--</div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background: #F99B10;height:926px">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: although its  now remaining two columns on every screen but they are not centered

Comment: Hi, I run the code snippet and it is aligned to the center. This is how it looks on my screen. [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/NNDRRfX.png)